# ошибка компиляции при использовании std::bind2nd

Tags: c++

Очень долго старался понять в чем же ошибка, когда я использую std::bind2nd.

Поиск через std::bind проходит успешно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
//...

bool equal(const std::pair< int, std::string >& p, const std::string& s)
{
    return p.second == s;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> list;
    //...
    list[5] = "error";
    list[6] = "filled";
    //...

    const std::string for_chack ="error";
    // первый способ поиска
    auto I = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(),
                 std::bind(equal, std::placeholders::_1, for_chack));
    ++I;
    std::cout << I->first << std::endl;
    // второй способ
    auto J = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(),
                 std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(equal),  for_chack));
    ++J;
    std::cout << J->first;

    return 0;
}
```

при поиске вторым способом выдается ошибка:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.0\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\backward\binders.h:163: error: 'typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::pointer_to_binary_function<const std::pair<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, bool>; typename _Operation::result_type = bool; typename _Operation::first_argument_type = const std::pair<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&]' cannot be overloaded
       operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type& __x) const
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::bind1st` и `std::bind2nd` не работают если среди параметров есть ссылки. Измените сигнатуру функции, так, чтобы она принимала значения или указатели, и все заработает.

```
bool equal(const std::pair< int, std::string > p, const std::string s)
{
    return p.second == s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, сейчас уже не рекомендуют использовать bind2nd (а в 17 стандарте и [вообще удалены](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) ) и подобные - есть лямбды

```
// второй способ
auto J = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), [for_chack](const std::pair< int, std::string >& p) {
    return for_chack == p.second;
});
```

Comment: что уже не рекомендуют использовать bind2nd, я знал,  я сам давно не использоваль ее, потому забыл (ответ yrHeTaTeJlb).  Ваш ответ очень полезен _ применение лямбды  привлекателней